# How to determine an area is unimodal or bimodal automatically

Tags: distributions, image-processing

I have an image containing the elevation of an area (digital elevation model) and I need to determine whether this image contains buildings or not automatically.  If it contains buildings I would need to remove it.   If not the image should be smooth.  I am thinking to try to determine whether the image has unimodal or bimodal distribution.  If it is bimodal it means the image contains buildings.  How can I determine an image has bimodal or unimodal distribution automatically? Any suggestions?

Comment: You need criteria for unimodal and bimodal, not just in terms of how big a peak you must have for a peak on a distribution to be called a mode (i.e. minor bumps can be ignored, but what is a minor bump) but also in terms of whether and how you bin or smooth your observed distributions before trying to identify modes. That said, this is likely be a standard problem in image processing with an enormous literature; I just don't know what it is.